# Configure Logging level in Python for each file individually

Tags: python, logging, levels, log-level

I'm using

```
logging.basicConfig(format=log_format, level=logging.DEBUG)
```

in my main script. I like seeing DEBUG messages in most cases. But I want to hide all DEBUG messages from a certain script - lets say connectionpool.py. How can i set connectionpool.py's Log level to INFO while having the rest at DEBUG?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, you don't set them by file, but by logging handler name.

Assuming it's `urllib3.connectionpool` that's bothering you (it's generally pretty noisy on `DEBUG`),

```
logging.getLogger('urllib3.connectionpool').setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

If it *really* is disabling a file you're after, you could also set up a [custom logging filter](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/logging.html#filter-objects) on your logger to swallow those log records altogether before they're output.

Assuming you haven't set up a more complex hierarchy to split logging output,

```
logging.getRoot().addFilter(lambda rec: 'connectionpool.py' not in rec.pathname)
```

would disallow all messages emitted from a module with `connectionpool.py` in the name.